# Proving closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

I'm curious. I have this set $$\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$$ and a binary operation defined by: $x*y = x+y + xy$.

How do I prove closure of this operation? It seems obvious to me that that operation yields a real number, but I just don't know how to prove it. I was looking for exactly what a Real number is, so I can use the definition, but I am having trouble finding such a definition.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use the fact that $x + y + xy$ is a real number, but you said you were working in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1\}$, so you have to prove that if $x,y \neq -1$, then $x * y$ can never be $-1$.

Comment: and $x*y = -1$ iff $x(1+y) = -(1+y)$. Does it ring a bell?

Comment: Elvis, I think you misunderstood the question. I was asking how to prove closure for Real numbers. And to prove whether something is automatically a real number. Pedro answered my question, though. Thanks for the input though

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $x+y+xy=-1$. This means $$xy+x+y+1=(x+1)(y+1)=0.$$
So either $x=-1$  or $y=-1$.